# How to make an inline <span> go to the next line when one of them is to wide?

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap badges and I'm struggling to get all the `<span>` elements to appear on the next line below when they get to large.

My Page current looks like this in mobile:

**Joe Bloggs**

**(Bigger Badge)**

**Joe Bloggs Brother (SMALL BADGE)**

How do I configure this so when the `<span>` element movest the others do to.

My Code:

```
<span class="UserNameBadges badge bg-primary rounded-pill"> {{ displayusernames(user.names) }} </span>
```

I've tried using pseudo-elements to get this working but I can only get it effect one of the elements and not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did this is within in the css. I made it so when the display gets so small I display the span as a block and to fit-content.

Looked like so:

```
@media (max-width:660px)  {
    .UserNameBadges {
        display: block;
        width: fit-content;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add either a custom class including `white-space: pre`. That will make an element not linebreak but move completely to a new line instead. Bootstrap-5 class for it is `text-nowrap`:

```css
div {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  width: 7em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div>
  <span>0 1 2 3 4</span>
  <span class="text-nowrap">5 6 7 8 9</span>
</div>
```